# Eclipse Plug-in : Displaying warning message in Eclipse using AST , DOM

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am learning Plug-in development and code manipulation using Abstract Syntax Tree and DOM.
I want to code a plug-in which will display a **warning** (see image) on the left hand side of the Eclipse Java code editor based on some condition in the testing code.

[image: sample warning message]

example scenario :
Right now warning message is displayed in eclipse when we do not use any declared variable in Java. I want to display warning message when (Just for example) any variable is assigned value 10 (lets say).
I know how to create Plug-In, Extract variables, expressions and declaration using AST. But I have no idea about how to display warning message.

which API or package is used for it?
Can someone please show me the path for this?

Comment: This is a 'marker' created with the `IMarker` interface

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using eclipse markers (`IMarker`).
Refer below link for more details on how to create an eclipse marker.

https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html

The `MarkerUtilities` class provides methods to create markers easily.
You need to add the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` plug-in to the dependencies.

For showing the same in editor use `markerAnnotationSpecification` extension point. This is used to define a mapping between markers and editor annotations automatically, with specified formatting.

Refer: http://cubussapiens.hu/2011/05/custom-markers-and-annotations-the-bright-side-of-eclipse/